# Playing custom push notification sound via Firebase Cloud Messaging Console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I have a push notification setup via `Firebase Cloud Messaging Console`.

In the payload, I added `sound` as my key and `custom_sound.wav` as my value.

My sound file (custom_sound.wav) is in `Copy Bundled Resources` of the project.

When I test the notification, the default sound continues to play instead of the custom sound file.

Separate from the notification via the console, the sound *does* play via `Firebase Cloud Functions` with the similar payload I send.

Can anyone advise?

I was looking into handling from the delegate function `didReceiveRemoteNotification` but read it only fires when the notification is tapped on. I also printed out the payload from `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and it prints the "sound" key/value outside the "aps" object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to Firebase support, they confirmed a custom notification sound cannot be played via the Firebase Cloud Messenger Console. A feature request has been filed.